# XSTL 2 navigate inside a document node variable

Tags: xslt

so, I have two document node variables, of which the first is static and the second is dynamically created.

```
<xsl:variable name="my_document_node_variable1" as="document-node()">
    <xsl:document>
        <root>
            <element>1</element>
            <element>2</element>
            <element>3</element>
        </root>
    </xsl:document>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="my_document_node_variable2" as="document-node()">
    <xsl:document>
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="$my_document_node_variable1/root/element">
                <new_element>
                    <!-- some content here -->
                </new_element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:document>
</xsl:variable>
```

The problem is: Inside the for-each-loop, starting with the second cycle, I want to access the element I have created in the preceeding cycle, i.e. the new_element-element.

Edit: I'm sorry, it seams it was by no means clear what I meant. Second attempt to explain:

When it comes to

```
<xsl:for-each select="$my_document_node_variable1/root/element">
```

for the first time, everything is allright. Let's say, the for-each-loop creates content like this:

```
<new_element> hi hi </new_element>
```

The variable "my_document_node_variable2" should now look like this:

```
<root>
<new_element> hi hi </new_element>
</root>
```

But now for the second cycle of

```
<xsl:for-each select="$my_document_node_variable1/root/element">
```

What I want to do here is: Take what you created in the preceding cyclye and transform it.
So, I have to get access to

```
<new_element> hi hi </new_element>
```

from inside of

```
<xsl:for-each select="$my_document_node_variable1/root/element">
```

I hope, it's clear now.

Is there a way or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are close. All you need to do is select the node `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$my_document_node_variable2">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="my_document_node_variable1" as="document-node()">
        <xsl:document>
            <root>
                <element>1</element>
                <element>2</element>
                <element>3</element>
            </root>
        </xsl:document>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="my_document_node_variable2" as="document-node()">
        <xsl:document>
            <root>
                <xsl:for-each select="$my_document_node_variable1/root/element">
                    <new_element>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </new_element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </root>
        </xsl:document>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**

I think this is what you want:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$my_document_node_variable2">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>            
</xsl:for-each>
```

Full Code:
    
    
        
        
            
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    1
                    2
                    3

Output:

```
<root>
    <new_element>1</new_element>
    <new_element>2</new_element>
    <new_element>3</new_element>
</root>
```

**Full Code Revised:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$my_document_node_variable2">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="my_document_node_variable1" as="document-node()">
        <xsl:document>
            <root>
                <element>1</element>
                <element>2</element>
                <element>3</element>
            </root>
        </xsl:document>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="my_document_node_variable2" as="document-node()">
        <xsl:document>
            <root>
                <xsl:for-each select="$my_document_node_variable1/root/element">
                    <new_element>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </new_element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </root>
        </xsl:document>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that's not what I meant. I've tried to explain it in other words again.

Comment: Thanks again. But sorry, but that's still not what I want. Every XPass expression with "this" (.) will refer to the content of "$my_document_node_variable1" because the for-each-loop processes elements within $my_document_node_variable1. However, I want to get accesso to the content of the second document node: $my_document_node_variable2. And this can't be done this way.

Comment: My code grabs the data from `<element>` and outputs it to  `<new_element>`. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No, sorry. To get the data from `<element>` is absolutely no problem. My problem is to get the data from inside of $my_document_node_variable2 which is in `<new_element>` and which was created by the for-each-loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on your requirement, but in general, if you are working with multiple sets of nodes, you need to bind variables to nodes rather than relying on the context item. For example

```
<xsl:for-each select="$A/node-set-1">
  <xsl:variable name="N1" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$B/node-set-2">
      <xsl:variable name="N2" select=".">
         .....
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think that would solve the problem (I've tried it. But a variable declared before a for-each-loop simply couldn't contain the elements to be generated by the following for-each-loop). I've edit my question in order to make my requirement clear.